# Scalable/Reusable Authorization Model

Tags: asp.net, ajax, authorization, script#

Ok, so I'm looking for a bit of architecture guidance, my team is getting a chance to re-cast certain decisions with a new feature that we're building, and I wanted to see what SO  thought :-) There are of course certain things that we're not changing, so the solution would have to fit in this model. Namely, that we've got an ASP.NET application, which uses web services to allow users to perform actions on the system.

The problem comes in because, as with many systems, different users need access to different functions.  Some roles have access to Y button, and others have access to Y and B button, while another still only has access to B.  Most of the time that I see this, developers just put in a mish-mosh of if statements to deal with the UI state.  My fear is that left unchecked, this will become an unmaintainable mess, because in addition to putting authorization logic in the GUI, it needs to be put in the web services (which are called via ajax) to ensure that only authorized users call certain methods.

so my question to you is, how can a system be designed to decrease the random ad-hoc if statements here and there that check for specific roles, which could be re-used in both GUI/webform code, and web service code.

Just for clarity, this is an ASP.NET web application, using webforms, and [Script#](http://projects.nikhilk.net/ScriptSharp/) for the AJAX functionality.  Don't let the script# throw  you off of answering, it's not fundamentally different than asp.net ajax :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Moving from the traditional group, role, or operation-level permission, there is a push to "claims-based" authorization, like what was delivered with WCF.

[Zermatt](https://connect.microsoft.com/Downloads/DownloadDetails.aspx?SiteID=642&DownloadID=12901) is the codename for the Microsoft class-library that will help developers build claims-based applications on the server and client. Active Directory will become one of the STS an application would be able to authorize against concurrently with your own as well as other industry-standard servers...

Answer (score 1):

In Code Complete (p. 411) Steve McConnell gives the following advice (which Bill Gates reads as a bedtime story in the Microsoft commercial).

"used in appropriate circumstances, table driven code is simpler than complicated logic, easier to modify, and more efficient."

"You can use a table to describe logic that's too dynamic to represent in code."

"The table-driven approach is more economical than the previous approach [rote object oriented design]"

Using a table based approach you can easily add new "users"(as in the modeling idea of a user/agent along with it's actions). Its a good way to avoid many "if"s. And I've used it before for situations like yours, and it's kept the code nice and tidy.

Comment: Well, the user and his permissions are definitely likely to be table based ... but are you suggesting that the configuration of each view (ie. which actions are mapped to which permissions/roles) be table based as well?